# Saving user profil and persistency

Tags: ios, image, swift, save, alamofire

I wonder about a simple and good way to save user profil after authentication.

I request a http request which will get a name, surname, mail and the user of its profil picture.

Where saving the name/username/mail ? NSUserDefault ? No, because I want that if the NSUserDefault informations are lost, I can get the user profil without forcing an http request. So I thought about using the Archiving ? But what about the image ? We convert it into NSData using UIImagePNG.. method ?

So, I want some advice about what I want to do if possible

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I think NSUserDefaults is a viable option. Data will only be lost when the user uninstalls the app. All data remains accessible even after an update. When the user uninstalls the app, *all* data is lost anyway, nothing you can do about that.

Sample implementation below (with getter and setter functions):

```
// setter
    func setLoggedIn(){
        userDefaults.setValue(1, forKey: "loggedIn")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

// getter
    func isLoggedIn() -> Bool{
        if let loggedIn: AnyObject = userDefaults.valueForKey("loggedIn"){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

Or for storing for example the user's first name:

```
// setter
    func setUserFirstName(val:String){
        userDefaults.setValue(val, forKey: "userFirstName")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

// getter
    func getUserFirstName() -> AnyObject{
        if let val: AnyObject = userDefaults.valueForKey("userFirstName"){
            return val
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could use plists quite easily then archive to documents directory.

there's a good tutorial at this link that should help
[plist tutorial](http://x-code-tutorials.com/2013/06/05/using-plist-files/)